# Pattern for reverse-accessible logic changes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm trying to find a design pattern or a best practice, or some other solution for a problem with keeping back versions of business logic within my application.  Specifically, I am looking to find a way to determine which logic was used to issue an insurance policy.

I currently have code which looks like this:

```
public double FixedDeductibleSurchageAmount()
{
    double percent = FixedDeductibleSurchargePercent();
    double base_premium = CollisionPremium() + TheftPremium();
    return (base_premium * percent);
}
```

I am needing to make a change to the business logic so that this function looks more like:

```
public double FixedDeductibleSurchageAmount()
{
    double percent = FixedDeductibleSurchargePercent();
    double base_premium = CollisionPremium() + TheftPremium() + MedicalPremium();
    return (base_premium * percent);
}
```

Where I run into trouble is that existing policies should rate with the previous logic.  Is there a design pattern for this?  If not, are there any good ways to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strategy pattern sounds most applicable.  Probably you'd need a factory method or some such that takes in a date to return the appropriate strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use additional data of some form to keep track of precisely what algorithm was used to obtain your data; you'll probably need to change your persistence representation to maintain versioning information about the algorithm used to derive your results.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you might consider making things like MedicalPremium or TheftPremium a Get-only property, rather than a parameterless function.  They fit that paradigm very well.

There are any number of ways you can solve this problem.  Some examples:

1) Switch to the new code and add a flag to the user data so that MedicalPremium automatically returns 0 for old users.  This is particularly easy if you stored your data in XML; the old data just won't have the flag, and it won't affect your deserialization of the data because XML is flexible.

2) Make the class that contains your function MedicalPremium a base class, and make MedicalPremium virtual.  Override it in the derived class, which is your new version.  Newer users are the derived class.  Old users are created as the base class.  For the old users, it always returns 0.  Properties can also be virtual just as functions can.

Comment: Actually, `MedicalPremium()` exists for all users, I'm simply adding it to this particular surcharge, so it cannot return a 0 for older users.  And they are referenced as methods because I'm in the white-board stages of a redesign, so I just dumped them in there for examples.

Comment: So make a function MedicalPremiumNew that returns MedicalPremium for new users only, and 0 for old users, and the rest of what I said still applies; or just make FixedDeductibleSurchageAmount virtual instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is: [the Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).  You can use this to extend the behavior of a class with additional wrapper classes.  In the example below I combine this with the Template Method Pattern to achieve what I believe you are looking for.

```
public class BaseSurchargePolicy {
    protected abstract double BasePremium { get; }
    protected abstract double FixedDeductibleSurchargePercent { get; }
    public double FixedDeductibleSurchageAmount{
      get
      {
        return (BasePremium * FixedDeductibleSurchargePercent);
      }
    }

    protected ICollection<string> _ProcessorsUsed;
    public IEnumerable<string> ProcessorsUsed 
    { 
      get { return ProcessorsUsed; }
    }
}

public class OldSurchargePolicy : BaseSurchargePolicy 
{

    protected double BasePremium 
    { 
        _ProcessorsUsed.Add(GetType().Name);
        return CollisionPremium + TheftPremium; 
    }
    protected double FixedDeductibleSurchargePercent { get; set; }

    public double CollisionPremium { get; set; }
    public double TheftPremium { get; set; }
}

public class MedicalSurchargeDecorator: BaseSurchargePolicy
{
    private BaseSurchargePolicy _wrapped;
    private double _medicalPremium;
    public MedicalSurchargeDecorator(BaseSurchargePolicy wrapped, double medicalPremium) 
    {
        _wrapped = wrapped;
        _medicalPremium = medicalPremium;
    }

    protected double BasePremium 
    { 
      get 
      {
        _ProcessorsUsed.Add(GetType().Name);
        return _wrapped.BasePremium + _medicalPremium; 
      }
    }
    protected double FixedDeductibleSurchargePercent { 
      get { return _wrapped.FixedDeductibleSurchargePercent }
    }

}
```

Comment: I know how to use decorators, but I do not see how they could apply here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a chance to look at Martin Fowler's Patterns of Enterprise Architecture he talks about individual instance methods, which isn't entirely the same as what you have, but is very similar.  It's a great book in any case.

In the meantime, I think you might have to start considering your functions as also being data, and store in your database which function was used.  You don't need (but may want) to store the function text, but you do need enough information to determine at run time which method to call.  You asked about patterns, and obviously you have a strategy pattern going on here, which you could reference, but I don't know if it will be especially helpful.